# Swagger-Codegen custom settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-codegen

I am using `swagger-codegen` to generate my client-side C# classes. It does the job, but there are a few things I'd like to customize:

1) Most importantly, how I tell it which namespace, or perhaps base namespace, to use? Right now all of the genned classes have `IO.Swagger.Model` namespace, how do I change that?

2) All of my generated models start with I... as in ICustomer... is there any way to autostrip that first I if the class name starts with 2 caps, and the first letter is an I?

3) If 2 can be done, is there a way to have it append a : `IWhatever`? So if it's trying to gen `ICustomer`, I'd like to see:

```
public class Customer : ICustomer
```

Can this be done?

4) For my last question, I am using this command-line:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate 
     -i http://localhost:57772/MyService/swagger/v1/swagger.json 
     -l csharp -o C:/Code/AutoGenned/MyService
```

The problem is that it adds this to the path:
src\main\csharp\IO\Swagger

Is there a way for me to not have this added to the path?

5) Finally, and least importantly, it gens 4 folders: `Api`, `Client`, `Model`, and `Properties`. Is there a way to only gen the `Client` and the `Model` folders?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on getting a response from `swagger-codegen` team and trying stuff out on my own:

1) To fix the namespace, I had to create a `config.json` file that has basically this:

```
{
  "packageName": "My.Namespace.Whatever"
}
```

now my run command is

```
    java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate 
     -i http://localhost:57772/MyService/swagger/v1/swagger.json 
     -l csharp -o C:/Code/AutoGenned/MyService 
     -c config.json
```

2) Can't replace, but I can prepend... so instead of having a class named `ICustomer` I decided that `ApiICustomer` made more sense... so to the above command, I added

```
--model-name-prefix Api
```

3) Still not sure if/how this is possible.

4) Looks like a new change is coming down the pipe that will change how this works. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2837

5) Based on the info here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#selective-generation You can do it by adding `java` system properties, like this `java -Dwhateverproperty`. So the end result, not including any fix for #3 is:

```
java -Dmodels -DsupportingFiles -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate 
     -i http://localhost:57772/MyService/swagger/v1/swagger.json 
     -l csharp -o C:/Code/AutoGenned/MyService 
     -c C:/Code/SwaggerCodeGen/config.json 
     --model-name-prefix Api
```

Answer (score 13):

For point 1), in addition of using a config file ( `-c config.json`),

you could also use the option directly: `-DpackageName=My.Namespace.Whatever`

Comment: The config.json approach works for me, while the -Dpackagename= approach doesn't.